# My cube is not displayed properly in opengl

Tags: c, opengl, 3d, glut, glu

I have code that simulate throwing of the cube, but it's not drawed properly (more far side is hover near side).

[image: https://i.imgur.com/Uky9VYR.png]

What's wrong? I tried to use different functions and parameters which works with z-buffer but it did not help. It's black screen or not displayed properly.

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <GL/glut.h>
float z = 7.0f, y = 0, x = 0;
float v0 = 0.2;
float alfa = 5;
float fi = 5;
float r = 1;
float dt = 0.01;
float g = 9.80665f;
float t = 0;
float omega = 0;
float vY = 0, vX = 0, vZ = 0, Y = 0, X = 0, Z = 0;
float ymax = 0, xmax = 0, zmax = 0, tD = 0, tm = 0;
void display()
{

glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);

glLoadIdentity();
gluLookAt(xmax + 10, zmax, ymax+10, 
    0.0, 0.0, 0.0,    
    0.0, 2, 0.0);   

glPushMatrix();
glColor3f(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
glBegin(GL_LINES);
glVertex2f(0.0f, 0.0f);
glVertex2f(333, 0.0f);
glEnd();

glBegin(GL_LINES);
glColor3f(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
glVertex2f(0.001f, 0.0f);
glVertex2f(0.001f, 333);
glEnd();

glBegin(GL_LINES);
glColor3f(0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
glVertex3f(0.001f, 0.001f, 0.0f);
glVertex3f(0.001f, 0.001f, 333);
glEnd();
glPopMatrix();

glPushMatrix();
static float angle = 0.0f;
angle += omega;

// glTranslatef(X-xmax-r, Z-zmax, Y-(xmax+ymax+zmax));
glTranslatef(X, Z, Y);
glRotatef(angle, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
glScalef(r, r, r);
glBegin(GL_QUADS);

glColor3f(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
glVertex3f(-0.5f, -0.5f, 0.5f);
glVertex3f(0.5f, -0.5f, 0.5f);
glVertex3f(0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f);
glVertex3f(-0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f);

glColor3f(0.5f, 1.0f, 0.5f);
glVertex3f(-0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f);
glVertex3f(-0.5f, -0.5f, 0.5f);
glVertex3f(-0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f);
glVertex3f(-0.5f, 0.5f, -0.5f);

glColor3f(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
glVertex3f(0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f);
glVertex3f(-0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f);
glVertex3f(-0.5f, 0.5f, -0.5f);
glVertex3f(0.5f, 0.5f, -0.5f);

glColor3f(1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
glVertex3f(-0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f);
glVertex3f(0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f);
glVertex3f(0.5f, 0.5f, -0.5f);
glVertex3f(-0.5f, 0.5f, -0.5f);

glColor3f(1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
glVertex3f(-0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f);
glVertex3f(0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f);
glVertex3f(0.5f, -0.5f, 0.5f);
glVertex3f(-0.5f, -0.5f, 0.5f);

glColor3f(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
glVertex3f(0.5f, -0.5f, 0.5f);
glVertex3f(0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f);
glVertex3f(0.5f, 0.5f, -0.5f);
glVertex3f(0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f);

glEnd();
//   glPopMatrix();
glutSwapBuffers();
}

void timer(int value)
{
glutPostRedisplay();
glutTimerFunc(15, timer, 0);
if (Z >= 0) {
    vX = v0 * cos(alfa * (3.14 / 180)) * cos(fi * (3.14 / 180));
    vY = v0 * cos(alfa * (3.14 / 180)) * sin(fi * (3.14 / 180));
    vZ = v0 * sin(alfa * (3.14 / 180))- g * t;
    Z = z + (v0 * sin(alfa * (3.14 / 180))) * t - 1 / 2.0 * g * t * t; 
    X = t * vX;
    Y = t * vY;
}
t += dt;

}
void obsluhaReshape(int width, int height) {
glViewport(0, 0, width, height);
glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
glLoadIdentity();
if (width == 0) width++;
const float aspect_ratio = (float)(width) / (height);
gluPerspective(100, aspect_ratio, 0, zmax + 10);
}
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
z = atof(argv[1]);
v0 = atof(argv[2]);
alfa = atof(argv[3]);
fi = atof(argv[4]);
r = atof(argv[5]);
omega = atof(argv[6]);

tD = (v0 * sin(alfa * (3.14 / 180)) + sqrt(pow(v0 * sin(alfa * (3.14 / 180)), 2) + 2 * g * z)) / g;
vX = v0 * cos(alfa * (3.14 / 180)) * cos(fi * (3.14 / 180));
vY = v0 * cos(alfa * (3.14 / 180)) * sin(fi * (3.14 / 180));
zmax = z + (v0* v0* sin(alfa * (3.141592 / 180))* sin(alfa * (3.141592 / 180))) / (2 * g);
xmax = tD*vX;
ymax = tD * vY;

printf("tD = %.2fs\nxmax = %.2fm\nymax = %.2fm\nzmax = %.2fm\n", tD, xmax, zmax, ymax);
glutInit(&argc, argv);
glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_SINGLE | GLUT_RGB | GLUT_DEPTH);
glutInitWindowSize(640, 640);
glutCreateWindow("DU6");
glClearDepth(100.0);
glDepthFunc(GL_LEQUAL);
glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
glutDisplayFunc(display);
glutTimerFunc(0, timer, 0);
glutReshapeFunc(obsluhaReshape);
glutMainLoop();
return 0;
```

Comment: I don't understand the problem. Can you take a picture (screenshot)?

Comment: @user253751 https://imgur.com/Uky9VYR

Comment: What if you delete `glDepthRange(0.0, 100.0);`?

Comment: are the purple and green sides always in front when it rotates?

Comment: @user253751 yes

Comment: it's strange because you have the symptoms of forgetting to turn on the depth buffer, except you did turn it on.

Comment: Since you still had the problem when you removed glDepthRange, I will remove it from the question to avoid red herrings. It shouldn't be there and I don't think 100 is a valid number for it

Comment: Can you edit your question to show how you are running the program? Instructions on how to build it would be nice too (although I figured it out myself).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
gluPerspective(100, aspect_ratio, 0, zmax + 10);
                                  ^ nope
```

Never set the `zNear` argument of `gluPerspective()` [to zero](https://registry.khronos.org/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/gluPerspective.xml):

> Depth buffer precision is affected by the values specified for `zNear` and `zFar`. The greater the ratio of `zFar` to `zNear` is, the less effective the depth buffer will be at distinguishing between surfaces that are near each other. If
>
> `r = zFar / zNear`
>
> roughly `log2(r)` bits of depth buffer precision are lost. **Because r approaches infinity as `zNear` approaches 0, `zNear` must never be set to 0.**

So to maximize depth buffer precision you should shoot for the largest value that doesn't cause clipping.  For small, close-in scenes like yours something `0.1` or `0.01` should work.

Comment: Ok, but it didn't help too

Comment: Oh, now it works, sorry